# Does the Series $\sum_{\substack{k=-\infty\\k\neq0}}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k}$ Converge?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to prove that this series converges, although I'm not entirely convinced that it does:

$$\sum_{\substack{k=-\infty\\k\neq0}}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k}$$

This is a two-sided infinite series of Fourier coefficients for a real valued 1-periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$, if that makes any difference.  I haven't been able to find a way, does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Edit: Maybe the best way would be to somehow adapt the fact that the sum of the nth roots of unity is equal to zero..

Comment: You should exclude $k=0$

Comment: Ah you are correct.  It's done but it looks ugly, a mod should feel free to clean it up if they know a more elegant way.

Comment: That way does look better Norbert, although since it's not absolutely convergent I'm worried that not specifying the order in which we sum the terms would be unacceptable.  I think I actually might change them both to how Fabian did it.

Comment: Ok, I don't mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum does not converge absolutely as
$$\sum_{\substack{k=-\infty\\k\neq0}}^{\infty}\left|\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k}\right|
= 4 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin (k\pi/10)|}k \geq
 \frac{4}{5}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2j+1} = \infty.$$
For the inequality, I have taken only the terms with $k=5(2j+1)$.

Maybe you are interested in another notion of convergence; summing the terms in the order $k=1,-1,2,-2, \dots$ leads to a finite result...

*Edit:*

As it turns out the OP is also interested in the sum
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k}.$$
Let us look at the real part of this sum. We have
$$\mathop{\rm Re} S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\pi k/5) - 1}{k}.$$
All terms in the sum are negative, so we can find a upper bound by only taking the terms with $k=5(2j+1)$, $j\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Thus,
$$\mathop{\rm Re} S \leq  - \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{2}{2j+1} =-\infty$$
and the series thus not converge.

Comment: Alternately: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(\pi k/5)/k$ does converge, and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)/k$ doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The two series
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k},
\qquad
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k}
$$
both diverge, but the "principal value"
$$
\lim_{K \to \infty} \;\left(\sum_{k=-K}^{-1}\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k}
+
\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi ik}{5}} - 1}{k}
\right)
$$
converges to $-i 4\pi/5$.
Add the limiting value $-i\pi/5$ for the $k=0$ term, and get $-\pi$ for your result.

Comment: Ah so it doesn't converge, I'm curious what is the general strategy to show this?

Comment: @Thoth: you can check out my answer.

Comment: @Fabian: but your answer is only for absolute convergence, am I missing something?

Comment: @Thoth: I will add some notes about the sum from $k=1,\dots,\infty$.